# Installing Linksys on Ubuntu machine

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, windows-xp, drivers, wireless-adapter

I recently set up an old XP desktop with Ubuntu 14.04. The computer was running XP Pro and was giving me trouble with the Linksys Wifi card. The signal kept going in and out so I switched.

Now I face the problem of installing the Linksys software on Ubuntu, the install disc does not boot, nor can I launch the installer from the drive. It does not currently have an internet connection and is not dual booting XP.

What can I do to install the Linksys software? Is there a way to copy the contents of the disc over to the HDD like a driver? Guess even though its probably obvious , I am new to Linux.

Comment: What is the model number of the Wifi card?

Comment: It is model WMP300N